# Classic ASP site only works if server is open via remote desktop

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, web-deployment

I have deployed the classic ASP website onto IIS 8 on a server. Now the classic ASP site only works if I have kept the server desktop open via remote desktop. If I close the remote desktop window and try to access the website, I get 500 Internal server error.

I have gone mad trying to resolve this issue from past few days.

Comment: Do you mean the site only works if you are logged on to the server (via remote desktop)? If so, is the site configured to run as your username?

Comment: Firstly, look at your server logs. Secondly, this isn't really a question for [so]. Try asking on [webmasters.se]

Comment: @acfrancis Yes, the site only runs when the server is kept open via remote desktop. Site is configured to run on ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Comment: Sounds like the site (or one of its dependencies) is tied to your user's desktop session. I think you need to look at what the website code is doing. Is it able to serve static files at least?

Comment: ASP site is accessing the COM+ component installed on the same server. I am not able to access any page.

Comment: Just found out that when remote desktop session is closed, the error is because of "Server.CreateObject Failed" so something there is bound to remote desktop session. This driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the solution for the issue. The solution was with configuration of the COM+ component. The "Identity" of the component was set to "Interactive User - The Current logged on user". I changed it to "Network service" and the website is working properly even when RDP session is closed.